# How do I adopt an orphaned table from another database for use in Views in drupal 7 data module?

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm trying to build a view from custom tables which are located in another database called 'academy'. My Drupal installation uses database 'drupal'. I've updates Drupal's settings.php file with:

```
$databases = array();

#DEFAULT DRUPAL DATABASE
$databases['default']['default'] =  array (
      'database' => 'drupal',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
);

#ACADEMY DATABASE


    $databases['academy']['default'] =  array (
          'database' => 'academy',
          'username' => 'root',
          'password' => '',
          'host' => 'localhost',
          'port' => '',
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'prefix' => '',
    );
```

And cleared cache. But when I go to 'Adopt Tables' in the data module I don't see any of my tables from the 'academy' database.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Did you configure Schema module (/admin/structure/schema/settings) and set "Database connection to use" to your "academy" database?

Answer (score 2):

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'abc',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'xyz' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'xyz',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => '127.0.0.1',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I have done it like this and it's working. If your otherdatabase tables name is 
different, then you can call it directly; otherwise, call it with your database_name.table name.

Comment: This essentially creates the same array as my code. It's not that I can't connect to my database, it's that I can't load views from it. I will have to keep digging. Perhaps there is a module or patch that can do it.

Comment: You checked whether your 2nd database is connected and returning any data or not? If it is connected just check in your views file that whether you are returning $data in module-name_veiws_data() function.